# Nonhomogenous Infinite String PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So I have this question where I need to find $u(x,t)$ such that:

$$ u_{tt}-c^{2}u_{xx}=x+ct; -\infty<x<\infty\\
u(x,0)=\sin x \\
u_{t}(x,0)=x^{2} $$

The instructor mentioned it would be "easy" if I used change of variables, but my T.A. told me that I should memorize Duhamel's principle. Is there any way around using Duhamel's principle or is my T.A. correct? I'm really confused because I don't remember going over Duhamel's in lecture.

Comment: try to change variables into $r=x+ct$, $s=x-ct$.